# Do paper wallets need to be updated?

Tags: wallets, homestead, paper-wallets

I've created a paper wallet at myetherwallet. Recently I've heard wallets need to be updated since the homestead release.

#### Do paper wallets need to be updated in some way?

I was under the impression that a paper wallet could be created then left for years without having to do any kind of updates. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No. *clients* need to be updated. MyEtherWallet.com has updated the geth instance they use and so you do not need to do anything.

If you downloaded the repo, you can download a new version which has been updated to support checksums. Otherwise, no need to do anything.